# Showing a set is not norm bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider the set $K = \{x(n) : x(n) \in \ell^p, \sum |x(n)| < 1\}$ $(0 < p < 1)$. I have shown that this set is weakly bounded, but I am now asked to show it is not originally bounded. where $\ell^p$ is metrized by 
$$
d(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x(n) - y(n)|^p
$$
My idea was as follows, but I was told this was incorrect because I only consider a special case, and my sequence technically is not in $K$.

I was told this should be an easy fix, and to fix $p$, then show how that for any $M>0$ there is a sequence in K such that  its norm is bigger that $M$ (hint: partial sum of your sequence). I am confused by the provided hint. Here is what I have.

To show that the set $K$ is not originally bounded we observe the following counter example. Consider 
$$
\sum \frac{1}{2}\left (\frac{1}{n}\right )^2 = \frac{\pi^2}{12} < 1
$$
Then we notice that this sequence is in $K$ however if $K$ were originally bounded for $0 < p < 1$. Consider $p = 1/2$. Then 
$$
\sum \left | \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^2 \right |^p = \sum \left (\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{n} \right)^2\right )^{1/2}
$$
$$
= \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left (\frac{1}{n} \right )
$$
However this is a divergent series. Therefore $K$ is not originally bounded.

I feel that if I only consider the partial sums then the sequence will be finite and I wont be able to prove the claim. 
If anyone would be kind enough to help me extend this argument or help clarify the hint I would be very grateful.

Comment: The problem is your sequence $x(n)$ does not lie in $l^{1/2}$ and therefore it is not in $K$ (which should be written as $K(1/2)$). The answer given below also has this problem. It's easy to fix by considering truncations of the sequence that end in all $0$'s. There's also a problem with quantifiers. Do you fix a $p\in (0,1)$ and then define $K?$ I think that's what's going on but it should be clearer.

Comment: @zhw. **Agree.** Actually I showed that my sequence it's not in $l^p$ in the second part. Corrected the proof. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $K$ is not originally bounded, let's consider the following sequence:

$$x=(x_n)_n,\quad x_n=\frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}},$$

where $\alpha>0$ is a real paremeter to be choose. Note that $\sum_{n\geq 1} x_n <\infty$. Define $M=M(\alpha)=\sum_{n\geq 1} x_n$, and take $z^{(m)}=(z_n^{(m)})_n$,

$$z_n^{(m)}=\begin{cases}x_n/(M+1)&,\text{ if }n\leq m;\\
0&,\text{ if }n>m.
\end{cases}$$.

Hence $z^{(m)}\in K$ for every $m\geq 1$. But

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 1} |z_n^{(m)}|^p&=\sum_{n\leq m} \frac{1}{(M+1)^p}\frac{1}{n^{(1+\alpha)p}}\\
&=\frac{1}{(M+1)^p}\sum_{n\leq m}\frac{1}{n^{(1+\alpha)p}}.
\end{align*}
Taking $\alpha\in(0,1/p-1)$ we see that for every $A$ there exist an $m$ such that the sum $\sum_{n\leq m}\frac{1}{n^{(1+\alpha)p}}>A$. Then $K$ is not bounded in that metric.

Comment: I am a little confused by the notation, does $x = (x_n)_n = (x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean by this notation. I will change it.

Comment: no reason to change I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful!